# Print which Radio-ToggleButton is in down state

Tags: python, radio-button, kivy

I am new to both Python and Kivy. We are developping this application for an assignment and I am working on the preferences page. My labels, textinputs, togglebuttons and button are all in the right place and working, but I am struggling with how I can get the output of these buttons.

Basically, I would like to print the output like this, when someone presses the confirm button:

```
Name: Blabla
Mood reminders: 2 per day
Diary reminders: 1 per day
```

I figured on_press would not work since that would print a value everytime a button is pressed instead of only when confirm is pressed.

Right now my .py code looks like this

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

# Builder.load_file('preferences.kv')

class MyFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    def mood_buttons(self):
        pass
    def diary_buttons(self):
        pass

    def print_specs(self):
        print("Name: " + self.name.text


class PreferencesApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyFloatLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PreferencesApp().run()
```

And my .kv language file looks like this

```
<Label>
    font_size: 20
<TextInput>
    font_size: 20
<Checkbox>
    size_hint_x: .20
<MyFloatLayout>:
    name: name
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text: "Name: "
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.08
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.1, "center_y": 0.85}
        TextInput:
            id: name
            multiline: False
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.07
            pos_hint:{"x":0.5,"center_y":0.85}

        Label:
            text: "How many mood reminders would you like?"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "top": 0.75}
        BoxLayout:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.55}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.1
            ToggleButton:
                text:"Zero"
                id: m0
                group: "mood_popups"
                on_press: self.mood_buttons()
            ToggleButton:
                text:"1 per day"
                id: m1
                group: "mood_popups"
            ToggleButton:
                text:"2 per day"
                id: m2
                group: "mood_popups"
            ToggleButton:
                text:"3 per day"
                id: m3
                group: "mood_popups"

        Label:
            text: "How many diary reminders would you like?"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "top": 0.55}
        BoxLayout:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.35}
            size_hint: 0.8, 0.1
            ToggleButton:
                text:"Zero"
                id: d0
                group: "diary_popups"
            ToggleButton:
                text:"1 per day"
                id: d1
                group: "diary_popups"
            ToggleButton:
                text:"1 per two days"
                id: d2
                group: "diary_popups"
            ToggleButton:
                text:"1 per week"
                id: d3
                group: "diary_popups"

        Button:
            text: 'Confirm'
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.1
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.25, "top": 0.2}
            on_press: root.print_specs()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access all the `Buttons` in a group using the `get_widgets()` method. So your `print_specs()` method can be:

```
def print_specs(self):
    print("Name: " + self.name.text)
    
    # get mood reminder
    mood_reminder = ''
    for toggle in ToggleButton.get_widgets('mood_popups'):
        if toggle.state == 'down':
            mood_reminder = toggle.text
            break
    print('Mood reminders:', mood_reminder)

    # get diary reminder
    diary_reminder = ''
    for toggle in ToggleButton.get_widgets('diary_popups'):
        if toggle.state == 'down':
            diary_reminder = toggle.text
            break
    print('Diary reminders:', diary_reminder)
```

Comment: Why do you only have to mention id m0 and d0? Is it unnecessary in this case to give them al their own id?

Comment: Actually, you don't need to mention any ids, and no ids are needed. The `get_widgets()` method is a static method of `ToggleButton` and returns a list of Buttons that are in a specific group. I have improved my answer above.